# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вернуть json файл только с объектами, если у нас имеется файл со вложенными массивами, в которых есть объекты

Tags: javascript, json

Есть json файл

```
data = [
  [
    1: {
      elem: '1',
      elem2: '2'
    },
    2: {
      elem: '3',
      elem2: '4'
    }
  ],
  [
    1: {
      elem3: '5',
      elem4: '2'
    }
    2: {
      [
        el: '1',
        el2: '2'
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Нужно получить в формате

```
data = [
  1: {
      elem: '1',
      elem2: '2'
    },
    2: {
      elem: '3',
      elem2: '4'
    },
    3: {
      elem3: '5',
      elem4: '2'
    },
    4: {
       el: '1',
       el2: '2'
    }
]
```

Подскажите, как его отформатировать?

Comment: Это не валидный JSON.

Comment: спасибо, разобралась, json был валидный, консоль в хроме отображала так, не сразу поняла